# How do you resize an image through pixel scaling?

Tags: adobe-fireworks, resize, creative-cloud, transform

I use Adobe's Creative Cloud to generally resize images...but I came across a strange use case. I want to resize a graphic of mine...but not using a standard scaling formula. I want to resize my image pixel by pixel through some pixel scale factor. So, if my image has one pixel, and I resize it by a scale factor of two, I would expect one pixel to take up four pixels, and so forth. But when I try to double the scaling on an image in Adobe Fireworks, for example, the image compensates some pixels to a different color. So how can I achieve a pixel scaling effect like this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Looks like I had to choose `Nearest Neighbor` in the resize image options, which works perfectly under Fireworks!

`Image size -> Resample image -> Nearest neighbor` is the path.